# Detail page w/ embedded VF page: Rerender page block w/o refreshing detail page

Tags: visualforce, rerender

I've been working with a vf page that sits in a standard page layout, that when I click a link I want it to rerender the vf page and not the Salesforce page it sits in.

I have the code working in that when you click the link the page rerenders and loads the data I expect. However, it refreshes the entire page and just displays the vf page without the Salesforce page layout. Only in Chrome and Firefox. In IE, the vf page rerenders and keeps the rest of the Salesforce page untouched.

Is there a syntax that I should use to ensure that the vf page rerenders inside the page layout?

Example vf page code:

```
<apex:page standardController="Account" extensions="EnhancedContactRelatedListCtrl" sidebar="false" showHeader="false">
<apex:form id="frm">
        <base target="_top"/>
        <apex:stylesheet value="{!URLFOR($Resource.EnhancedContactRelatedList, 'css/jquery.dataTables.min.css')}"/>
        <apex:includeScript value="{!URLFOR($Resource.EnhancedContactRelatedList, 'js/jquery-1.11.3.min.js')}"/>
        <apex:includeScript value="{!URLFOR($Resource.EnhancedContactRelatedList, 'js/jquery.dataTables.min.js')}"/>

        <style>
            table.dataTable thead .sorting_asc {
            background: url("{!URLFOR($Resource.EnhancedContactRelatedList, 'images/sort_asc.png')}") no-repeat center left;
            }
            table.dataTable thead .sorting_desc {
            background: url("{!URLFOR($Resource.EnhancedContactRelatedList, 'images/sort_desc.png')}") no-repeat center left;
            }
            table.dataTable thead .sorting {
            background: url("{!URLFOR($Resource.EnhancedContactRelatedList, 'images/sort_both.png')}") no-repeat center left;
            }
            .se-pre-con {
            position: fixed;
            left: 0px;
            top: 0px;
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
            z-index: 9999;
            background: url({!URLFOR($Resource.EnhancedContactRelatedList, '/images/loader.gif')}) center no-repeat #fff;
            }
        </style>
        <apex:pageBlock title="Contact List" id="conlist" >
        <apex:actionFunction action="{!delContactRecord}" name="delContactAF" rerender="conlist" status="counterStatus">
            <apex:param name="contactId" value="" assignTo="{!idSelectedContactId}"/>
        </apex:actionFunction>

        <apex:outputpanel rendered="{!!isCorporateAccount}" >
            <a href="{!newContactUrl}" target="_top" style="margin:4px">New Contact</a>
            <a href="{!mergeContactUrl}" target="_top" style="margin:4px">Merge Contact</a>
            <!-- <a href="/003?id={!currentAccount.Id}&rlid=RelatedContactList" target="_top" style="margin:4px">View All Contacts</a> -->
        </apex:outputpanel>
        <apex:commandLink action="{!toggleInactive}" value="Show All Contacts" rendered="{!showActiveContacts}" >
            <apex:actionSupport event="OnClick"
                reRender="conlist"
                status="counterStatus" />
        </apex:commandLink>
        <apex:commandLink action="{!toggleInactive}" value="Show Active Contacts" rendered="{!showInactiveContacts}" >
            <apex:actionSupport event="OnClick"
                reRender="conlist"
                status="counterStatus" />
        </apex:commandLink> 

        <div style="margin-bottom:10px;" />
        <div class="se-pre-con"/>
        <div style="height:400px;overflow:auto;">

            <table id="contactTableID" class="display" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
                <thead style="background-color:#F5F5F5">
                    <tr>
                        <th style="background-image:none;"></th>
                        <th style="background-image:none;"></th>
                        <th>Name</th>
                        <th>Practice</th>
                        <apex:repeat value="{!$ObjectType.Contact.FieldSets.EnhancedContact}" var="fs">
                        <th>
                            {!fs.Label}
                        </th>
                        </apex:repeat>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <apex:repeat value="{!mapContactIdToContactWrapper}" var="key">
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <a href="/{!mapContactIdToContactWrapper[key].objContact.Id}/e" target="_top" style="margin:4px">Edit</a>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <apex:outputLink value="javascript:if (window.confirm('Are you sure?')) delContactAF('{!mapContactIdToContactWrapper[key].objContact.id}');"> Del
                            </apex:outputLink>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <a href="/{!mapContactIdToContactWrapper[key].objContact.Id}" target="_top">
                                <apex:outputText value="{!mapContactIdToContactWrapper[key].objContact.Name}"/>
                            </a>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <apex:outputText value="{!mapContactIdToContactWrapper[key].strName}"/>
                        </td>
                        <apex:repeat value="{!$ObjectType.Contact.FieldSets.EnhancedContact}" var="fs">
                        <td class="tdClass">
                            <apex:outputField value="{!mapContactIdToContactWrapper[key].objContact[fs]}">
                            </apex:outputField>
                        </td>
                        </apex:repeat>
                    </tr>
                </apex:repeat>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
    </apex:pageBlock>    
        <script>
            $(".se-pre-con").fadeOut("slow");
            $(document).ready(function() {
                var oTable =$('#contactTableID').DataTable({
                        "scrollY": "310px",
                        "columnDefs": [ { //remove the sortable from first column
                        "targets": 0,
                        "orderable": false
                    }]
                });
            });
        </script>
        <!--Action status for loading symbol-->
        <apex:actionstatus id="counterStatus">
            <apex:facet name="start">
                <div class="waitingSearchDiv" id="el_loading" style="background-color: #fbfbfb; height:100%;opacity:0.65;width:100%;">
                    <div class="waitingHolder" style="top: 100px; width: 91px;">
                    <img class="waitingImage" src="{!URLFOR($Resource.EnhancedContactRelatedList, '/images/loader.gif')}" title="Please Wait..." />
                    <span class="waitingDescription">Loading...</span>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </apex:facet>
        </apex:actionstatus>
</apex:form>
```

In the example I am clicking on the commandlinks that are toggleinactive

EDIT:

Controller code example:

```
//refreshes the contact list after the show inactive is toggled
public PageReference toggleInactive(){
    if(!showInactiveContacts){
        showInactiveContacts = TRUE;
        showActiveContacts = FALSE;
    }
    else{
        showInactiveContacts = FALSE;
        showActiveContacts = TRUE;
    }
    fetchContacts();
    return null;
}
```

Comment: what is the toggleInactive() method in apex class?

Comment: Added, it sets inactive or active boolean and then goes through a method to retrieve the contacts. In the contact query the boolean filters records or not.

Comment: I had some bad experiences with rerendering pageblocks. Back then the solution was to wrap the pageBlock inside an apex:outputpanel and rerender the outputpanel. Worth a shot..